# Access call log from SL4A

Tags: android, python, sl4a

Is it possible to access the call log (history of outgoing, incoming and missed calls) of an android phone using a python code in the SL4A environment?

Comment: figured out a way and have given the python script here : https://github.com/myramnath/androidContactsLog-Analytics

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit function for accessing the CallLog.Calls object.

It may be possible in the ContactsFacade e.g. queryAttributes or queryContent but you would need to investigate further there.